# Basic Mathematics Probability

Tags: probability, combinatorics, statistics

i am a bit busy with something on mathematics, and i wonder if you could help me a bit.

Here is the deal: During final  examinations, 50% of the students passed Geography. 10% passed Sociology , and 7% passed both of them. We pick randomly one student. What is the chance that he/she failed on both of these two exams?

To me this is straight forward. But maybe i miss something bigger in the end.

In fact, i have pictured this problem as a venn diagram and let A=50% and B=10% then A intersect B = 7% . So the answer should be 1 - [A + B] =40% . Can this be SO easy?

Comment: no, what is the percetage of people who passed at least one class? $A+B=50+10$ counts the people who passed both twice!

Comment: @kaine people who passed at least on class should be: A-7% + B-7% (those passed only one exam) +7% (those who passed both exams). 53% , i think.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to subtract $|A\cap B|$, from A + B, too!

Otherwise you're "over counting" those who *passed both*, each of which is counted in $A$ and counted in $B$; we want to count them once, only. $$\begin{align} 1 - [A + B - A\cap B] & = 1 - [0.5 + 0.1 - 0.07] \\ \\ & = 1 - 0.53 \\ \\ &= 0.47 = 47\%\end{align}$$

Comment: Thank you. I was thinking that was the right answer from the very beginning to be honest. i think i understood it now.

Comment: You're welcome, Cynth!

Comment: @amWhy: Needs another TU +1